# Regular expression to allow spaces between words (without special characters) but removing spaces at the beginning

Tags: regex

I'm working on validating a field in which you can enter

- **letter** (0-9)
- **characters** (a-Z),
- **spaces**,
- **'-'** and
- **'_'**

but you **cannot** enter special characters **(!@#$%)**

You can also add more space characters (at the end and beginning)
but after the first spacing must be at least one allowed character

Good:

`"        some 123    exa_mple m-s-g    "`

`"123abc"`

`"           a"`

Bad:

`"                      "`

`"123!@#abc"`

Comment: Could you add what you've got so far ?

Comment: Is there a difference between bad and wrong? Also, what are you actually looking for? Are you only looking for a regex that gets a valid grouping? what is the actual question?

Comment: " difference between bad and wrong" - no, i will change description

Answer (score 1):

You could use a negative lookahead to assert that special characters do not appear anywhere in the input:

```
^(?!.*[!@#$%])\s*[A-Za-z0-9_-][A-Za-z0-9 _-]*$
```

### Demo

Here is an explanation of the pattern used:

```
^                     from the start of the string
    (?!.*[!@#$%])     assert that no symbols occur anywhere
    \s*               match optional leading whitespace
    [A-Za-z0-9_-]     match one allowed character (non space)
    [A-Za-z0-9 _-]*   then match zero or more allowed characters (including space)
$                     end of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

I' use:

```
^(?!\h+$)[\w\h-]+$
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of string
  (?!\h+$)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't only spaces
  [\w\h-]+      # character class, alphanumeric, underscore, space, hyphen
$               # end of string
```

[Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/cmNP2d/1)